# archive.canonical.com and security.ubuntu.com InRelease files being sent as archives

Tags: apt, software-installation, update-manager

I have no clue what is going on, all of my other repos update just fine except these two. Upon visiting the links in my browser, they appear as text, as they should.

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease

EDIT: The error is this: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
THESE ARE THE ONLY TWO PACKAGE ARCHIVES RECEIVING THIS ERROR.

I am on a mobile connection, which does have a transparent proxy, but I am tunneled on a VPN while doing this.

I have already cleared /var/lib/apt/lists to no avail.
Any help is greatly appreciated,
Walaryne

Comment: This is a different problem, the post which you linked to does not solve my problem.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is different? To me it looks like the exactly same error. Have you checked whether apt might need to have a proxy set up?

Comment: If I needed a proxy, then why are all of my other ppas/repos downloading just fine? Also its a transparent proxy, not like the ones you must connect to for some isps, its done transparently as the name entails.

Comment: It seems to be an issue where a gzip file is being downloaded in apt, and wget, but my browser is loading the file as text, like it should be. Personally I think these repos might be bypassing the vpn I'm using to stop the nosplit issue from happening in the first place.

Comment: So you get a `InRelease.gz` file when you run `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease`?

Comment: Without the gz at the end, yes, I think so. It looks like compression when viewing the file in a text editor.

Comment: "It looks like compression" can also be any other binary format or just random garbage. Please check the file format of the `InRelease` file you got using the `file InRelease` command.

Comment: Kk, thanks for your help so far. I'm sending this on my phone atm. When opening the file, it defaulted to the archive manager btw.

Comment: application/x-gzip, I was right.

Comment: And if you unpack that file, what does it contain? (I'm just curious though, I have to admit I have no idea how to proceed with that)